# My character runs around on their own after picking up an object

Tags: collision-detection, unreal-4, blueprints

I have a weird bug on my hands.

I am trying to create an event whereby the character walks into an object and automatically picks it up once the collision occurs.

The character can pick up the object (when the overlap begins it is attached to a socket on the character)

But immediately after this happens, the character runs around on their own without any input from me.

When the bug occurs, the character moves backward, facing and circling the point where the collision occurred.
It's quite bizarre.

I created a project from the top-down template, then added the actor to be picked up and created the actual Blueprint.
It is the only blueprint I've created.

Any ideas as to what could be happening here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to disable the object collision once the object had been picked up.
Set the object collision to ignore the pawn channel like so.

[image]